# Как создать бесконечный цикл в бесконечном цикле на Python

Tags: python

Не получается создать бесконечный цикл в таком-же цикле. Ошибок нет, но программа просто пропускает часть кода начиная со второго while.

```
 while True:
        print("Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа")
        user_input = input(": ")
        if user_input == "Добавить" or "добавить":
            while True:
                numb1 = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
                numb2 = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
                print(str(numb1), str(numb2))
```

Comment: Исключений, может, и нет. А вот ошибка как раз есть. Условие `if user_input == "Добавить" or "добавить":` всегда истинно.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> while True:
...     print("Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа")
...     user_input = input(": ")
...     if user_input.lower() == "добавить":
...         while True:
...             numb1 = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
...             numb2 = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
...             print(str(numb1), str(numb2))
...
Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа
: добавить
Введите первое число: 10
Введите второе число: 5
10.0 5.0
Введите первое число: 15
Введите второе число: 3
15.0 3.0
Введите первое число: 123
Введите второе число: 10
123.0 10.0
Введите первое число:
```

Программа точно следует логике, которую вы в неё заложили, если исправить неправильно составленное условие.
То, что идёт после цикла, не пропускается - до него попросту не доходит очередь. Если вам нужно, чтобы после цикла выполнялся ещё какой-либо код, имеет смысл сделать выход из цикла:

```
>>> while True:
...     print("Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа")
...     user_input = input(": ")
...     if user_input.lower() == "добавить":
...         while True:
...             numb1 = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
...             numb2 = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
...             print(str(numb1), str(numb2))
...             if numb1 == numb2: # условие, при котором цикл заканчивается. Я использовал условие равенства двух чисел, у вас оно может быть другим
...                 break
...         print('***** Бесконечный цикл закончен, код дальше выполняется')
...
Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа
: добавить
Введите первое число: 3
Введите второе число: 2
3.0 2.0
Введите первое число: 3
Введите второе число: 5
3.0 5.0
Введите первое число: 5
Введите второе число: 5
5.0 5.0
***** Бесконечный цикл закончен, код дальше выполняется
Введите 'Добавить' чтобы добавить два числа
:
```

Что касательно ошибки в вашем коде:

```py
user_input = input()
if user_input == "Добавить" or "добавить":
    print('Это условие выполняется всегда!')
```

Вы можете сами это проверить. Дело в том, что с учётом приоритетов операций условие выглядит так:

```
if (user_input == "Добавить") or ("добавить"):
    pass # do something
```

Логическое выражение `user_input == "Добавить"` может принимать как истинное значение, так и ложное, а вот логическое значение строки `"добавить"` всегда истинно, т.к. любая непустая строка имеет истинное булево представление. Если хотите использовать именно такой подход к решению, а не приведением к нижнему регистру, условие должно иметь вид:

```
if user_input in ("Добавить", "добавить"):
    pass # do something
```