# Не понятен принцип срабатывания условного оператора if

Tags: python

Пытаюсь проверить, какое значение из словаря `cash` соответствует ключу `'op'`:

```
cash = {'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'eq': 0,
        'op': '-'}

if cash['op'] == '+' or '+=':
    print('plus', cash)
elif cash['op'] == '-' or '-=':
    print('minus', cash)
elif cash['op'] == '*' or '*=':
    print('mult', cash)
elif cash['op'] == '/' or '/=':
    print('div', cash)
else:
    print('WTF?')
```

Получаю: `plus {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'eq': 0, 'op': '-'}`

Несмотря на то, что значение `'op' : '-'`, почему-то срабатывает условие `if cash['op'] == '+' or '+='`.
Как исправить код так, чтобы проверка значения ключа `'op'` работало корректно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже давал недавно ответ на [подобный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1116778) вопрос.

---

Дело в том, что вы неправильно реализуете сравнение.
Операция `if cash['op'] == '+' or '+=':` равносильна `if (cash['op'] == '+') or ('+='):`, и если левый операнд `or` изменяет своё значение, то правый - непустая строка, а булево представление непустых строк всегда истинно.

Получается операция `if [True/False] or True`, что всегда равно `True`.

---

Если вам нужно сравнивать значение сразу со многими, воспользуйтесь оператором вхождения `in`:

```py
cash = {'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'eq': 0,
        'op': '-'}

if cash['op'] in ('+', '+='):
    print('plus', cash)
elif cash['op'] in ('-', '-='):
    print('minus', cash)
elif cash['op'] in ('*', '*='):
    print('mult', cash)
elif cash['op'] in ('/', '/='):
    print('div', cash)
else:
    print('WTF?')
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ с пояснением!

Answer (score 3):

```
if cash['op'] in ['+', '+=']:
    print('plus', cash)
...
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, он правильный, но решением только один можно пометить

Comment: @Kaderma Не проблема :)